# Filter HTML list based on input's value

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I have an HTML input and definition list:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="search">

<dl class="glossary">
      
  <dt>First</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>

  <dt>Second</dt>
  <dd>Duis dui mauris, interdum sed velit ac, fermentum eleifend sem.</dd>
    
</dl>
```

I am using AlpineJS and I would like to display the DT/DD pair if the value in Search Input is contained in the DT value.

For example, if input value is "fi" then only the first DT/DD pair will show because the DT value is **Fi**rst

I looked for solutions but I only found cases where list is populated by Javascript.

Comment: You should include your javascript as well so we can get an idea of where you're coming from.

Comment: You probably _should_ be populating the list with JavaScript so you don't have to parse it to sort values. What have you tried?

Comment: I have no javascript yet because I don't know where to start. The list is rendered server side. So when the page loads the list is already in the page.

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service; you are expected to make an attempt and then ask specific questions about your attempt.

Comment: *"I only found cases where list is populated by Javascript [...] when the page loads the list is already in the page"* - Does that make a difference?  Whether the list was populated client-side or server-side, it's populated.  It sounds like you're looking to write some functionality that takes place after the data has been populated on the page (dynamically filtering the data in some way).  That functionality probably isn't concerned with where the data originated.  I can't speak to what functionality is supported by Alpine.js, but does that preclude the use of plain JavaScript here?

Answer (score 1):

Using a [`watcher`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch) on the search pattern we can obtain the definition list with an [`x-ref`](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/ref). After that we loop over it and hide/show the respective elements. I have also applied the `toLowerCase()` method to make the search case-insensitive.

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="filter">
  <input type="search" placeholder="search" x-model="pattern">

  <dl class="glossary" x-ref="deflist">

    <dt>First</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</dd>

    <dt>Second</dt>
    <dd>Duis dui mauris, interdum sed velit ac, fermentum eleifend sem.</dd>

  </dl>
</div>


<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('filter', () => ({
    pattern: '',
    init() {
      this.$watch('pattern', (val) => {
        let keep_dd_node = false
        for (let item of this.$refs.deflist.children) {
          if (item.nodeName == 'DT' && item.textContent.toLowerCase().includes(this.pattern.toLowerCase())) {
            item.style.display = 'block'
            keep_dd_node = true
          }
          else if (item.nodeName == 'DD' && keep_dd_node) {
            item.style.display = 'block'
          }
          else {
            item.style.display = 'none'
            keep_dd_node = false
          }
        }
      } )
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```